# Force redirection to a particular controller from link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a view file of mine I have a code like this:

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure ?' } %></td>
```

So after clicking on this it's deleting that particular data form database. But this code is in a file named **profiles/index.html.erb** which is generated with the profile controller. 
Now after clicking on destroy link the control is going to the **links_controller.rb** not **profiles_controller.rb**. But I want this to get redirected to **profiles_controller.rb**, so that I can do certain operations while deleting in my `destroy` action in my profiles controller and then get redirected to **profiles/index.html.erb**, not **links/index.html.erb**.
How to do this??

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `link_to` is the destination of the link, ie. what you're linking to - it sounds like you're linking to the wrong place.

If you want to link to the profiles controller you need to do that (ie. change `link` to whatever your route to the correct action of the profiles controller is).